# URL per directory query-string

Tags: url, directory, query-string

I am building a web framework which is based on a hierarchical modular design. I've got components and components extending other components.

To access these components I'm looking for a nice syntax in the URL. As I'm using **Node.js**, I've got no restrictions whatsoever from existing web server software. Components are simply structured objects in JavaScript that can be piped together.

The URL scheme I use is:

```
/componentA/componentBextendsA/componentCextendsB
```

Now, I want to give each component it's own parameters. Intuitively I wanted to do this with directory-based query-strings, like:

```
/componentA?foo=bar&hello=world/componentB?foo=test/componentC?pie=
```

- componentA

  - `foo` = `bar`
  - `hello` = `world`
- componentB

  - `foo` = `test`
- componentC

  - `pie` = empty

The arguments can overlap, as one component can handle the same query parameter as the other.

My questions are:

- can clients break because of this?
- is there an already existing implementation of directory-query-strings?

Comment: Node.JS is unrelated for the question: it's platform/server independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the URI component perspective, the URI `/componentA?foo=bar&hello=world/componentB?foo=test/componentC?pie=` consists of the path `/componentA` and the query `foo=bar&hello=world/componentB?foo=test/componentC?pie=`. And inside the query component, both `/` and `?` are valid plain characters. So this URI should be handled correctly by clients.

If you want to parse this URI the way you’ve described, you can do the following:

```
var url = "/componentA?foo=bar&hello=world/componentB?foo=test/componentC?pie=";
var re = /([^?]+)(?:\?([^?\/]*))/g, match, components = [];
while (match = re.exec(url)) {
    components.push({path: match[1], query: match[2]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that doesn't a good idea. Current trend is to simplify urls, for clarity and because SEO. I don't know if that actually works, but pasing parameter in the `?var=value` format is being deprecated. I developed my own php framework, maybe I could give some ideas if you give me more info. (Sorry about my english)

Comment: Well, basically i'm providing data per component. Other components can use this data to extend on it. For example, `/files/` shows a list of files, `/files?search=foo` will filter the files, `/files?search=foo/somefile.txt/` will show the file `somefile.txt` regardless of the search paramter. It works kinda like the Unix pipe `|`, which pipes the output of one command to the input of another.

Comment: Maybe it's too much information for passing it in that way. The problem for using a positional order it I guess component could have a variable quantity of arguments. What about loading the skeleton and loading each component using ajax? Elgg framework uses that way for people profiles.

Comment: I'm not using a skeleton, nor AJAX. I'm building the webserver from scratch using Node.js.